# Are there any ways to put view slightly outside its parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

It's a question about Android layouts. Here's what I *eagerly* want to get:

[image: Layout]

Dark-gray is a LinearLayout. Orange is layout X and then Green is a FrameLayout. I need to put Green outside its parent - layout X. The layout hierarchy described can't be changed. The only option is layout X - it could be whatever you want.

Any ideas?

Comment: I hate to say it, but the only way I can think of is to use a FrameLayout to wrap everything, have the dark gray and orange in a linear layout and then lay the green layout over the others.  Which conflicts with your "The layout hierarchy described can't be changed".  Just out of curiosity, why can't it?

Comment: I think you can specify negative values for margins. Have you tried that? I think it works for layouts where you can have overlap (two objects on a canvas, for example). I'm not near an any editor, otherwise I'd try it myself. I know for certain you can have overlap if you entire layout is a canvas, but I'm not sure in your situation.

Comment: @Barak: It's basically a table (table row is on picture) and in some circumstances I need to move a single cell outside it's normal position, so Table/TableRow layouts are the only I can use.

Comment: @Gophermofur: Have already tried, it doesn't work. The child view is either clipped or fills the entire parent (depending on parent's android:clipChildren)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be the case. Unfortunately, it looks like the green part needs to be part of the parent container (Dark Grey), but a LinearLayout wouldn't work to get what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put the Green part in Layout X, because it can not be drawn outside its parents.

So, you should implements a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout (root Layout) as the parents of all of these Views.

And Put the Green View as the childView of the root Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_dark_grey"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_orange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_dark_grey"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_green"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="300dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I know there are ways to achieve it by using more appropriate layouts instead of the ones that I use. I'm still curious if there's a way to do it in my case.

Answer (score 77):

Use -

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

in every parent of your child view, then you put 'left margin' of your view to be negative,which will put your child view outside of parent view and will not even clip the view.

Comment: Negative margin is the winner!

Comment: Spot on! Cheers

Comment: @Denny - Unfortunately in my experience and other readings, clip seems to work differently depending on the android version (Why? I don't know. Maybe Google will make things work consistently some day) so it may not always be the solution being looked for.

Comment: beautiful, works like a charm.. you need to put these attributes on each and every parent of the view.

Comment: This should be the correct answer since it accomplished what the OP was looking for.

Comment: negative margin might not work in constraintLayout, in that case translationX and translationY could be used with negative values.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOrange">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```