# How to force layout content out of the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to recreate this layout:

[image]

and i manage to do it, but the layout can also change into this:

[image]

that forces part of the content out of the screen.

To make the change i make visible a hidden layout that correspond to the extra layout that shows up when a certain button is pressed and disappears.

Here is what i made:

[image]

The result when the extra content is visible:

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/edit_holder"
                android:layout_width="325dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/del_border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/del_item"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear_bege_20dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_holder"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_border"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner_edit"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="239dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:foreground="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nome_prod"
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/preto_escuro" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tam_txt"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/tamanho"
                        android:textColor="@color/por_usar" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tam_val"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/preco_ant"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/fade" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cor_t"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:text="@string/cor"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cor"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.2"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quanti"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="X x" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/preco_fin"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.2"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/bege" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/preto_escuro" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: Please ignore the different shape of the image, it`s not relevant for the problem.

To make it more clear, i just want to know how can i "push out of the screen" part of the content in the layout when the hidden layout is visible. I dont want any swipe effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mTak i  updated the question, to make it more clear.

Comment: Just set its visibility to `gone`

Comment: @mTak the question is about dealing with the layout aspect when it`s 'visible' , most of the time it will be in 'gone' but it can become 'visible' when a button is pressed.

Comment: Ok, you have from left to right a Linearlayout, an ImageView and another Linearlayout and in xml they are all visible. Explain which part of the content should be pushed out when the 1st LinearLayout will become visible.

Comment: Not possible with LinearLayout I think. Try to have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432422/are-there-any-ways-to-put-view-slightly-outside-its-parent-layout)

Comment: @mTak the part that would go off screen would be part of the layout that is to the right of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the swipe libraries you need to add

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
}
```

and this at to the top of your XML

```
<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:clickToClose="true">
```

for more info check this GitHub repository

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: maybe i was not clear in the question,  but i dont want a swipe function, the layout will be static, it just pushes part of the content "out" of visibility when the hidden layout if visible, can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set animations for that, using object animator write an animating function, then start it whenever you want!
Something like this:

```
private void hideLayout(){
  float startX = yourLayout.getX();
  float endX = 0 - yourLayout.getX();
  ObjectAnimator anim
         = ObjectAnimator.ofFlot(yourLayout,view.X.startX,endX);
  anim.setDuration(500);
  anim.start();
}
```

Comment: As i stated before i dont want animations, since this is used in a recyclerview that already provides a smooth trasition